# Are certain MATLAB functions only precise to a certain decimal? How precise is MATLAB really?

Tags: matlab, interpolation, precision

I am converting a program from MATLAB 2012 to 2016. I've been getting some strange errors, which I believe some of are due to a lack of precision in MATLAB functions.

For instance, I have a timeseries `oldTs` as such:

```
Time                   Data
-----------------------------
1.00000000000000001    1.277032377439511
1.00000000000000002    1.277032378456123
1.00000000000000003    1.277032380112478
```

I have another timeseries `newTs` with similar data, but many more rows. `oldTs` may have half a million rows, whereas `newTs` could have a million. I want to interpolate the data from the old timeseries with the new timeseries, for example:

```
interpolatedTs = interp(oldTs.time, oldTs.data, newTs.time)
```

This is giving me an error: `x values must be distinct`

The thing is, my x values *are* distinct. I think that MATLAB may be truncating some of the data, and therefore believing that some of the data is not unique. I found that other MATLAB functions do this:

```
test = [1.00000000000000001, 1.00000000000000002, 1.0000000000000000003]
unique(test)

ans =
     1

test2 = [10000000000000000001, 10000000000000000002, 10000000000000000003]
unique(test2)

ans =

     1.000000000000000e+19
```

MATLAB thinks that this vector only has one unique value in it instead of three! This is a huge issue for me, as I need to maintain the highest level of accuracy and precision with my data, and I cannot sacrifice any of that precision. Speed/Storage is not a factor.

Do certain MATLAB functions, by default, truncate data at a certain nth decimal? Has this changed from MATLAB 2012 to MATLAB 2016? Is there a way to force MATLAB to use a certain precision for a program? Why does MATLAB do this to begin with?

Any light shed on this topic is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Stray comment: If `oldTs.time` is uniformly sampled, then you could use `resample(oldTs.data, newTs.sampleRate, oldTs.sampleRate)` and bypass your precision problem.

Answer (score 1):

No, this has not changed since 2012, nor since the very first version of MATLAB. MATLAB uses, and has always used, double precision floating point values by default (8 bytes). The first value larger than 1 that can be represented is `1 + eps(1)`, with `eps(1) = 2.2204e-16`. Basically you have *less than 16 decimal digits* to play with. Your value `1.00000000000000001` is identical to `1` in double precision floating point representation.

Note that this is not something specific to MATLAB, it is a standard that your hardware conforms to. MATLAB simply uses your hardware's capabilities.

Use the [variable precision arithmetic](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) from the Symbolic Math Toolbox to work with higher precision numbers:

```matlab
data = [vpa(1) + 0.00000000000000001
        vpa(1) + 0.00000000000000002
        vpa(1) + 0.00000000000000003]

data =

 1.00000000000000001
 1.00000000000000002
 1.00000000000000003
```

Note that `vpa(1.00000000000000001)` will not work, as the number is first interpreted as a double-precision float value, and only after converted to VPA, but the damage has already been done at that point.

Note also that arithmetic with VPA is a lot slower, and some operations might not be possible at all.

Comment: Has this changed since MATLAB 2012?

Comment: @Sunden: This has not changed since the very first version of MATLAB. There never has been a time when MATLAB didn’t use double-precision floats to represent numerical values. Since MATLAB 5 (sometime in the late 1990’s) we can optionally use integers and single-precision floats, but you have to make an effort, and any of those would only make things worse for you.

Comment: @Sunden: The interpolation algorithm has changed at some point, it is possible that the old code wasn’t erroring out, but producing wrong results.